# How to update a recordset

Tags: vb6, ado

here is my code

```
Dim Cn1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim iSQLStr As String
Dim field_num As Integer


Set Cn1 = New ADODB.Connection
Cn1.ConnectionString = _
    "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
    "DefaultDir=" & "C:\path\"
Cn1.Open

iSQLStr = "Select * FROM " & "file.txt" ' & " ORDER BY " & txtField.Text
field_num = CInt(1) - 1
Set Rs1 = Cn1.Execute(iSQLStr)
lstResults.Clear

While Not Rs1.EOF
    DoEvents
    Rs1.Fields(field_num).Value = "qaz"
    If IsNull(Rs1.Fields(field_num).Value) Then
        lstResults.AddItem "<null>"
    Else
        lstResults.AddItem Rs1.Fields(field_num).Value
    End If
    Rs1.MoveNext
Wend
```

The error i get is in this line

```
Rs1.Fields(field_num).Value = "qaz"
```

it says "The current recordset does not support updating", what is wrong in the code?

Comment: You can't update/delete with the text ODBC driver I'm afraid, you would need to parse the file yourself.

Comment: so, whats should i do to manipulate large files (2 million lines text file) like i want to add line numbers in the text file.

Comment: Open it either entirely into memory and split into an array of lines, or line-by-line, then edit each as you see fit

Comment: i want to edit all at a time and the data keep on changing (updates). Is there anyway to update/edit a csv file in vb6 using sql?

Comment: You could always pull the file into a database and manipulate it that way. It's probably gonna be faster than anything else. Even Microsoft SQL Server Express allows importing files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is valid for text files but with SQL Server you need to change the LockTypeEnum Value setting to allow editing see this [link](http://www.timesheetsmts.com/adotutorial.htm), the default is [adLockReadOnly](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_open.asp#adLockReadOnly)

## Edit

According to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/csharpgeneral/thread/0be7a020-be05-4e6b-9948-a34ce5342051) it is not possible to edit a text file via ADO.